# ARRAY ELEMENTS PRODUCT

Tags: algorithm, sorting

How to check whether every pair of elements of an array are such that answer of multiplication of those pair exist in array.

```
Example:
example 1=a={1,2}; here 2*1=2 which exist in array
example 2=a={1,2,1}; here 1*2=2 so 2 exist,2*1=2 so this also exist.
example 3=a={3,4}; here 3*4=12 which doesn't exist in this array
so how we can check that this type of array exist or not.
```

Answer (score 0):

`$elements = array(
    array(1,2),
    array(1,2,1),
    array(3,4),
);`

`foreach ($elements as $subElements) {
    foreach ($subElements as $element) {
        $product = current($subElements) * next($subElements);
        if (in_array($product, $subElements)) {
            echo $product.' exists<br>';
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Store all elements in a unordered_map(C++) or hashmap(Java)
2. Run two `for-loop`: `[first_entry, last_entry)` *as outer* and `(outer_entry, last_entry]` *as inner loop*, do summation of key and check if the sum is present in the map. If not found, break out of outermost loop, and return `Doesn't exist`.
3. Else return `Exist`

Creating the map would take `O(N)` and checking the existence of pair sum would take `O(N^2)`

So, TC : `O(N^2)`

Answer (score 0):

Such array must have all but one elements equal to 1. Otherwise the array would be infinitely large.